# collapsing by groups and calculating n in data.frame using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains three variables:  treatment, dose, and outcome (plus or minus).  I have multiple observations for each treatment and dose.  I'm trying to output a contingency table that would collapse the data to indicate the number of each outcome as a function of the treatment and dose, as well as the number of observations.  For example:

```
treatment dose outcome    
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 1
treatmentA 1 0
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 2 1
treatmentA 2 1 
treatmentA 2 1
```

The desired output would be:

```
treatment dose outcome n
control 0 0 1 4
treatmentA 1 2 3
treatmentA 2 3 3
```

I've played around with this all day and haven't had much luck beyond being able to get a frequency for each outcome for each observation.  Any suggestions would be appreciated (including pointing out what parts of the R manual and/or examples) i've overlooked.

Thanks!

R

Comment: Can you give your data in recreatable format? maybe use dput ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using a wonderful package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(read.table( text = "treatment dose outcome    
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 1
treatmentA 1 0
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 2 1
treatmentA 2 1 
treatmentA 2 1", header = TRUE)
x[, list(outcome = sum(outcome), count = .N), by = 'treatment,dose']
```

produces

```
    treatment dose outcome count
1:    control    0       1     4
2: treatmentA    1       2     3
3: treatmentA    2       3     3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use extra libraries as suggested in other answers, you can try following.

```
> df
    treatment dose outcome
1     control    0       0
2     control    0       0
3     control    0       0
4     control    0       1
5  treatmentA    1       0
6  treatmentA    1       1
7  treatmentA    1       1
8  treatmentA    2       1
9  treatmentA    2       1
10 treatmentA    2       1

> dput(df)
structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", "treatmentA"), class = "factor"), 
    dose = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), outcome = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("treatment", 
"dose", "outcome"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Now we use `aggregate` function to get count and sum of `outcome` column

```
> nObs <- aggregate(outcome ~ treatment + dose, data = df, length)
> sObs <- aggregate(outcome ~ treatment + dose, data = df, sum)
```

Change names of of aggregated column appropriately

> names(nObs) <- c('treatment', 'dose', 'count')

```
> names(sObs) <- c('treatment', 'dose', 'sum')

> nObs
   treatment dose count
1    control    0     4
2 treatmentA    1     3
3 treatmentA    2     3


> sObs
   treatment dose sum
1    control    0   1
2 treatmentA    1   2
3 treatmentA    2   3
```

Use `merge` to combine above two by all columns by same name `treatment` and `dose` in this case.

```
> result <- merge(nObs, sObs)
> result
   treatment dose count sum
1    control    0     4   1
2 treatmentA    1     3   2
3 treatmentA    2     3   3
```

Comment: Seconding Arun here. It's always good to see some explanation alongside an answer.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14575719/1270695) for an interesting application of `aggregate`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, this is straightforward with the `data.table` library. First, load the library and read the data in:

```
library(data.table)

data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
treatment dose outcome    
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 1
treatmentA 1 0
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 2 1
treatmentA 2 1 
treatmentA 2 1")
```

Next, create a `data.table` with the `treatment` and `dose` columns as the table keys (indices).

```
data <- data.table(data, key="treatment,dose")
```

Then aggregate using `data.table` syntax.

```
data[, list(outcome=sum(outcome), n=length(outcome)), by=list(treatment,dose)]

    treatment dose outcome n
1:    control    0       1 4
2: treatmentA    1       2 3
3: treatmentA    2       3 3
```

Comment: Jason, you are a life saver.   Thanks to everyone else for the suggestions as well.

Comment: Great minds think alike - we've got almost identical answers within minutes of each other :). BTW, ``.N`` is a useful shortcut for the ``length`` of a sub-group.

Comment: @VictorK. Thanks for the type. I didn't know about `.N`

Comment: You are welcome. There are also .SD, .BY, .N, .I and .GRP (see ``data.table`` documentation).

Answer (score 2):

imho, sql is underrated. :)

```
# read in your example data as `x`
x <- read.table( text = "treatment dose outcome    
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 0
control 0 1
treatmentA 1 0
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 1 1
treatmentA 2 1
treatmentA 2 1 
treatmentA 2 1",h=T)

# load the sql data frame library
library(sqldf)

# create a new table of all unique `treatment` and `dose` columns,
# summing the `outcome` column and 
# counting the number of records in each combo
y <- sqldf( 'SELECT treatment, dose , 
                    sum( outcome ) as outcome , 
                    count(*) as n 
             FROM   x 
             GROUP BY treatment, dose' )

# check the results
y
```

Comment: perhaps you can add results too

Comment: `sqldf` is good if your data is already in some text file and you want to bypass getting data in R before doing such aggregation. If your data is already in R, then `sqldf` will add unnecessary overhead of sending and retrieving data to and from `sql`

Comment: @geektrader, In my opinion, it is nice to see different alternatives for a given problem.

Comment: @AnandaMahto agreed. I just wanted to state additional info regarding `sqldf`. :)

Comment: @geektrader sqldf gets the answer in one line of code.  that's as good as any other alternative here.  it's not like the extra half-second processing time makes a diff.  plus sql is incredibly intuitive and many R beginners do know sql already.

Comment: @geektrader and those who upvoted his comment. Benchmarks suggest otherwise.  See the benchmark references in the first paragraph on the sqldf home page where a couple of users found it ran faster than R`aggregate` on their problems.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck when I used `sqldf` my findings were otherwise. But by no means I claim my findings are conclusive. btw - just for the record, I didn't downvote this answer. I am interested in discussing various alternative. I am sure `sqldf` has it's place as right answer for some problem :)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck furthermore the examples cited where `sqldf` wins over `aggregate` are specific example where `sqldf` happens to be faster. Also the project homepage of `sqldf` itself says, that the purpose of `sqldf` is convenience rather than speed. It goes without saying that a prudent execution speed conscious programmer will check all the alternatives and decide on his/her own which solution to use.

Comment: @geektrader, The point is that the comments warning the reader to beware of sqldf's performance are misleading. Its not particularly slow and that is so much so that a number of users even use it to get a speed advantage over R.

Answer (score 2):

Here are another couple of options (even thought the `data.table` approach clearly wins in succinctness of syntax).

The first uses `ave` within `within`. `ave` can apply a function to a variable (the first variable mentioned) grouped by one or more variables. We wrap the output in `unique` after dropping the now unnecessary "outcome" column.

```
unique(within(df, {
  SUM <- ave(outcome, treatment, dose, FUN = sum)
  COUNT <- ave(outcome, treatment, dose, FUN = length)
  rm(outcome)
}))
#    treatment dose COUNT SUM
# 1    control    0     4   1
# 5 treatmentA    1     3   2
# 8 treatmentA    2     3   3
```

A second solution in base R is very similar to @geektrader's answer, except it calculates both `sum` and `length` in one call to aggregate. There is a "downside" though: the result of that `cbind` is a "column" in your `data.frame` that is actually a matrix. See the result of `str` to see what I mean.

```
temp <- aggregate(outcome ~ treatment + dose, df, 
                  function(x) cbind(sum(x), length(x)))
str(temp)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "control","treatmentA": 1 2 2
#  $ dose     : int  0 1 2
#  $ outcome  : int [1:3, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 3 3

colnames(temp$outcome) <- c("SUM", "COUNT")
temp
#    treatment dose outcome.SUM outcome.COUNT
# 1    control    0           1             4
# 2 treatmentA    1           2             3
# 3 treatmentA    2           3             3
```

I mention storage structure as a "downside" mostly because you might not get what you expect when you try to access the data in ways you might be accustomed to.

```
temp$outcome.SUM
# NULL

temp$outcome
#      SUM COUNT
# [1,]   1     4
# [2,]   2     3
# [3,]   3     3
```

Instead, you have to access it via:

```
temp$outcome[, "SUM"] ## or temp$outcome[, 1]
# [1] 1 2 3
```